# Stop a package if a percentage difference of counts is less than 1%

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, package, percentage

I have a package that runs weekly but it needs to stop if there is a difference of more than 1% in the counts.

Here is my query to get the percentage of the 2 counts:

```
USE MandatedReporting 
DECLARE @a AS float 
DECLARE @b AS float 
declare @c as float 

SET @a = (  SELECT Row_Count 
            FROM [MandatedReporting].[dbo].[DCFS_Weekly_File_Row_Count] WITH(NOLOCK) 
            WHERE TableName = 'MandatedReporting.dbo.MATCH_WEEKLY_V3' 
                  AND RunDate = (   SELECT MAX(RunDate) AS RunDate 
                                    FROM [MandatedReporting].[dbo].[DCFS_Weekly_File_Row_Count] AS ThisWeeksData WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                    WHERE TableName = 'MandatedReporting.dbo.MATCH_WEEKLY_V3')) 

SET @b = (  SELECT Row_Count 
            FROM [MandatedReporting].[dbo].[DCFS_Weekly_File_Row_Count] WITH(NOLOCK) 
            WHERE TableName = 'MandatedReporting.dbo.MATCH_WEEKLY_V3' 
                  AND RunDate = (   SELECT MIN(RunDate) AS RunDate 
                                    FROM [MandatedReporting].[dbo].[DCFS_Weekly_File_Row_Count] AS ThisWeeksData WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                    WHERE TableName = 'MandatedReporting.dbo.MATCH_WEEKLY_V3' 
                                    AND  ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(),CAST(RunDate AS DATETIME))) < 10)) 

set @c = (@a-@b) *100.0/@b SELECT @c as 'Count'
```

SQL Server 2008
Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention I am new to SSIS

Comment: What do you mean by stop?  Exit happily or throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for conditional split. After you execute your stored procedure in `Execute SQL Task` you need to store output in a variable and then implement conditional split based on output.

[image]

Only instead of writing out to a file you simply end your Data Flow or else if you want a nuclear option you can throw an error or do the same in stored proc:

```
begin
    raiserror('Foo Bar',16,1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the Info.

Comment: @Brian If that works for you please consider marking the answer as correct